# Getting Web Service data without using Async

Tags: c#, web-services, web, webclient

There is this webservice, which i need to get some information. This webservice has an Authentication Header, and two parameters embedded in the body of the request. I have wrote the method using `HttpClient` class:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        request.RequestUri = new Uri("URL");
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        request.Headers.Add("AUTHENTICATION_Key", "AUTHENTICATION_VALUE");
        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"P1\":\"V1\",\"P2\":\"V2\"}",Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

the problem has risen from where the project I need to use, is using DotNet 2.0 and in .Net 2 we cannot use asynchronize therefore I cannot use await and SendAsync() as well as ReadAsStringAsync() another problem is SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 is not available in .Net 2. and Im going to need it to get data from it.
I appriciate the help.

Comment: Are you saying this is a project from 2005?  If so, then why are you trying to use functions that are not available in that version of .net?

Comment: Thats exactly the point of this question. Im tring to find a solution.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading a 15 year old project to a modern version of .NET, (Framework 4.8, or Code 3.0)

Comment: The problem is that I cant, this system belongs to the employer, and the company wants to preserve its project with the current framework.

Comment: You could explain to them that IT projects have an end of life, and 2.0 is WAAAY past its bed time.   You could mention about how Windows 7 is no longer getting security updates (which is the same as your project), and it was only released in 2009.  Sometimes developers need to tell managers the reality really is "Upgrade your software".